# Javascript RegExp issues?

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching, qregexp, regexp-substr

I've been trying hard to solve a problem using Js. I must define a function using  RegExp that allows only 3 char words in which:

- The first two characters must be between a-z, excluding b
- The last character must be z or v

Tried to build many expressions but none of them seemed to work.

Help pls :c

Comment: If you show us what you have so far we can help you find why it's not working. Preferably include the program and inputs you're testing with.

Answer (score 0):

`^[a|c-z]{2,2}[z|v]$` will perfectly match.

Answer (score -1):

This regular expression will work for you: `var regex = /(a|[c-z]){2}(v|z)/`